# If formula contains specific text/symbol/function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

How can I detect if certain cells contains specific formula with specific text/symbols?

```
1. A formula which is =today(), or =date(), or =time()
2. A formula which starts with =(any alphabet letter)
3. A cell which starts with '
4. A formula which ends with any number
```

I use the formulas in conditional formatting.

Thank you.

Comment: `FORMULATEXT` will give you the text of a formula, you can then look for any string in it

Comment: Just an observation: p._phidot_ took the time to develop almost the entire solution for you.  For the last piece, you apparently found what you were looking for somewhere else.  Posting two other people's work as your own answer and accepting it is a little tacky.  It isn't clear where you found José Augusto's answer, but a better approach would have been to either link to that answer in a comment or work with p._phidot_ to add or reference that in the answer with attribution.  Then accept p._phidot_'s answer (which you could still do and delete your own).  (cont'd)

Comment: That would also award you both a little rep for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't mind about the rep and the little stuff. I don't know if I could get rep in this case (I can reward myself rep? If it were the case, I would have created multiple questions and posted multiple answers myself. A big loophole)

Comment: Initially I wanted to select both as the answers but the system didn't allow it. The aim is to spread knowledge and benefit everyone. I think this is most important (not the rep stuff). If I posted Q3 in the comment and selected that as the solution, it would be hard for people to notice it. Perhaps I shouldn't have shared my findings and just kept it silent. I could delete the answer if people think the accidental rep gain is a major concern. I don't mind the rep at all. Anyway I would ask p._phidot_ to update the answer. I could delete it if he prefers this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for Q3**

Open VBA and create a macro:

```
Option Explicit
Function ZIsApostrophe(rng As Range) As Boolean
    ZIsApostrophe = rng.PrefixCharacter = "'"
End Function
```

Use the custom function `ZIsApostrophe()` to check if a cell starts with ' .

For example type `ZIsApostrophe(A3)` to check if the cell A3 starts with ' . It will return the value TRUE or FALSE as the result.

Credit: José Augusto

---

**Answers for 1, 2, and 4**

1a ) =IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=TODAY()",1,0)

1b ) =IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(A1),5)="=TIME",1,0)

1c ) [ edit the 1b solution ]

2 ) =IF(AND(CODE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,1))>=65,CODE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,1))<=90),1,0)

[ you may refer the details of code() in the help file.. (: ]

4 ) =IF(AND(code(right(FORMULATEXT(A1),1))>=48,CODE(right(FORMULATEXT(A1),1))<=57),1,0)

Credit: p.*phidot*

Answer (score 1):

Ans for 1, 2, n 4 :

1a )  `=IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=TODAY()",1,0)`

1b )  `=IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(A1),5)="=TIME",1,0)`

1c )          [ edit the 1b solution ]

2 )   `=IF(AND(CODE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,1))>=65,CODE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,1))<=90),1,0)`

[ you may refer the details of code() in the help file.. (:  ]

4 )  `=IF(AND(code(right(FORMULATEXT(A1),1))>=48,CODE(right(FORMULATEXT(A1),1))<=57),1,0)`

Hope it helps.

note for Q3 :

a formula almost always starts with a "=" character.. it never starts with a characters.. unless you actually referring to a text value.. then you may use the if() + left() + edit the solution for Q2 .

Please share what you had tried and didn't work.. I'll help others to understand where you stuck at and help out. ( :

Comment: For Q3, sorry for the confusion. What I mean is the cell starts with the symbol apostrophe. It forces the input to be text only. Apostrophe is hidden in display. For example: '=1+1

Comment: For Q4 it could be. For example, =today()+5. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: updated Q4 answer. btw, '=1+1 is a string / text .. not a formula (as mentioned in the question)..

Comment: after a moment of thinking.. I propose this as the solution for Q3 : `=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="=",1,0)`

Comment: For Q3 this is a possible workaround but it will miss any cell which does not have = after ' . I tried using the code() but it didn't work. It appears there is no good way to detect '. Thank you.

Comment: next try.. `=IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1),"not a formula")`

Comment: Finally I found the answer for Q3. I combined yours with the answer for Q3 in one post. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it finally solved. Congratulations on the discovery.. ( :

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You could update your post and put the answer of Q3 together with your own. Then I will delete mine and select yours as the answer. Thank you. :)

Comment: its ok @masterton ,u did well. I don't mind the scoring/accept. I mind the walk on the learning path more. I'm happy as it is.. at least others can view this story & learn the "trial n error" part & say.. "hey, now I have the confidence to solve this.. " kind of thinking/feel. || Honestly, I truly glad that ur solved this. It give energy for both (all?) of us to do better. /(-_-)  || I'm ok with the current status, don't undo it.. embrace it ( I mean.. the learning part). || Only god can repay the site admin+mod+creator+maintainer+team for building this great online "be good" platform. ( :

Comment: Great. Thank you for your encouragement. I like to learn. I'm glad we can learn something new each day. Thank you so much for your help. I very much appreciate it. ^_^